# Validate username in Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form in Symfony2 where an Admin have to write the username of another user.

Is it possible to check before to send the form, if the username exist in my database? I use doctrine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom constraint, which is injected with your Entity Manager and checks if the username exists. [See the documentation for creating a custom constraint here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Another option would be to [write a data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) which converts a username string into a User object, which should ensure that user existed throwing a TransformationFailedException if she doesn't. This might be a bit easier because the example in the docs already creates the transformer as a service and shows you how to inject the entity manager.

Also, depending on how many users you have in your app, you could make the username option an [`entity` choice type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), and allow symfony to create a drop down with all of your users already in there.

EDIT:
Sorry, I missed the part about checking *before* you submit the form. The ideas above are still how you could implement on the server, but for the first two options you would need to use an Ajax request to test if the username was valid.